# How can I fix substring to read urls from object correctly?

Tags: javascript, typescript, algorithm

As the user is typing in a url, I am trying to iterate through an object so that no error message is thrown until a substring doesn't match the beginning of any of the urls in my object.

Object:

```js
export const urlStrings: { [key: string]: string } = {
  'www.costco.com': '',
  'www.walmart.com': '',
  'www.google.com': '',
  'www.facebook.com': '',
}
```

So the user will type and no error will be thrown until a substring is incorrect:

```js
w
ww
www.
www.c
www.ca <--- this should throw error
```

However, because I have subString set to 1, it only gives me the first letter of the url (item). I want to get everything from the first letter to the increasing index. I have a break in there that stops the for loop.

```js
const correctUrl = (value: string | null): string => {
  let errorMessage = ''
  let item: string
  let subString = 1

  if (value && typeof value === 'string') {
    // eslint-disable-next-line guard-for-in
    for (item in urlStrings) {

      if (value?.length <= item?.length && subString <= item?.length) {
        if (item.substring(0, subString) === value.substring(0, subString)) {
          errorMessage = ''
          break
        }
      }
      subString += 1
    }
  } else {
    errorMessage = 'Throw error'
  }
  return errorMessage
}
```

Any recs? Also, this is typescript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that's a bit more complicated than it needs to be. Array methods will make this pretty trivial. Put the keys of the object (the URLs) into an array, then check if `.every` one of those URLs *does not* start with the text typed. If so, then there are no potential matches, and you can return the error string.

```
const urlStrings = {
    'www.costco.com': '',
    'www.walmart.com': '',
    'www.google.com': '',
    'www.facebook.com': '',
};
const urls = Object.keys(urlStrings);
const correctUrl = (value: string | null): string => {
    if (value === null) {
        return 'Throw error';
    }
    return urls.every(url => !url.startsWith(value))
        ? 'Throw error' // None of the URLs matched
        : '';
}
```

The object of `urlStrings` seems a bit odd though. Unless the values of the object contain data in your actual code, you could consider starting out with a plain array instead.

```
const urls = [
    'www.costco.com',
    'www.walmart.com',
    'www.google.com',
    'www.facebook.com',
];
```

Comment: Seems like [Array.prototype.some()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) is a more appropriate function than the negation of `Array.prototype.every()`.  In theory, `.some()` should be able to short circuit upon the first occurrence that matches, whereas that's not the case with `.every()`...

Answer (score 2):

It maybe easier to use JS's native array methods to help you. Add the keys to an array, and then use [`some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) to check the strings against the value of the input. If the value matches none of them throw the error.

```js
const urlStrings = {
  'www.costco.com': '',
  'www.walmart.com': '',
  'www.google.com': '',
  'www.facebook.com': '',
};

const input = document.querySelector('input');
input.addEventListener('input', handleInput);

const validStrings = Object.keys(urlStrings);

function handleInput() {
  const { value } = this;
  const valid = validStrings.some(str => {
    return str.startsWith(value);
  });
  if (!valid) console.log('URL not valid');
}
```

```html
<input type="text">
```

Comment: I used a dictionary to have constant time look ups, but considering I am iterating through the strings maybe it doesn't matter?

Answer (score 1):

good question!

First off, I'd recommend looking into guard clauses -- your nesting so many layers deep that the logic gets way more complicated to track with.

I think your `Throw error` is aligned with the wrong if statement -- basically if it succeeds at all, it's never going to throw the error. If you reformat your code with my first suggestion, I think the placement should be pretty clear -- and you shouldn't need a break statement.

Good luck, feel free to ask follow ups!